# I need a chip identified: TI 36A2DKK

Tags: identification, smart-card, texas-instruments

I got a Smart Card reader out of a laptop. There's not much going on on the board, just the card receptacle on one side, with the contact springs, and two ICs on the back side:

A Cypress `CY7C63001 A-SC` USB micro controller, which is the bigger of the two, and finding datasheets for that is no problem.

Now the chip that interfaces the Smart Card chip, is a Texas Instruments `36A2DKK` (2nd line: `HC02`), no datecode. It's a 14 pin SOIC-150 package.

I can't really show you a picture, I don't have any camera or macro lenses, that would make a decent photo of the markings.

I checked the usual places for datasheets, and manufacturers websites, but I can't find a single thing about it. The datecode on the micro controller is `0406`, 4th week of 2006 would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a SN/CD54/74HC02 quad NOR. The "36A2DKK" is a lot code.

[source](http://e2e.ti.com/support/other_analog/etc_analog/f/247/t/60255.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide a source for your info?  It's not that I don't believe you.  It's just that this is extremely error prone.  I looked at the TI datasheet and other docs for the 74HC02 and couldn't find anything about how it's marked.

Comment: @DavidKessner: Source added.

Comment: Thanks, the HC02 looked suspiciously like 74-series logic, but I was a bit confused why they'd use that in a Smart Card reader (I was expecting something like a more sophisticated interface, with Vpp booster or something).